# Prevent child records from being deleted

Tags: permissions

I am not sure I have encountered a bug or just a problem with configuration.

Account object has a child object related by master detail relationship, hence it is controlled by parent. The user profile is configured to prevent deletes on the child object.

If user opens a record the delete button does not appear. However, we are using a package from AppExchange that allows us to manage records more easily. However, it's interface has built in delete buttons which WORKED. The record got deleted. I have even tried to delete the record that is owned by another user and it worked (perhaps the clue here is Accounts are set to Public Read/Write?)

What's even more interesting is that package provider claimed it is not possible and it should throw an error upon unauthorized delete. Which it did once when I tested. Next time it worked.

I realize developing a trigger would solve everything, but I am trying to understand the root of the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the button a custom, apex button?  If so, it's possible the ISV is running code in the System context / without sharing and ignoring permissions for deleting the child records.

Comment: I presume so as it is a VisualForce frame (with a custom controller) in a standard page layout. How do I find out what permissions the code is granted?